# HQL logging categories/selective hibernate HQL logging?

Tags: hibernate, logging

*All HQL* or *no HQL* logged is too blunt an instrument for me. Does anybody know of settings/parameters in hibernate which would allow me to prioritise/categorise HQL logging for different queries?

For instance, I would ideally want to be able to set a category or "query type" marker on each query and regulate the ../WARN/INFO/DEBUG/.. logging level for each of my query types.

I can see there are things like

- org.hibernate.event.spi.EventType, with contained events I could perhaps register listeners for and trigger logging on the listener according to my own settings somewhere.
- org.hibernate.Interceptor, which defines methods called for specific events in a session, which I could override for something similar.

But I couldn't immediately find any such entry points corresponding to running queries. An easy way I could imagine/wish for would be to set an annotation field on @NamedQuery but I don't see anything obvious there either..

Comment: No there isn't a way to do it. Why do you want to do it, I can hardly imagine a use case for which it would be useful?

Comment: The use case is log/performance analysis of a client system processing a lot of data. Some queries we are happy with, in other cases we cannot know in advance as they may be generated dynamically according to user settings, thus selectivity when calling the hibernate layer would be useful. While logging is good, we have had complaints about excessive logging before - this would be one way to cut down noise in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Logging those queries in a production system would adversely affect performance.

I would recommend using the analysis tools of the DB (e.g. Oracle OEM), instead to identify any costly queries. You can also directly query the system tables in many databases to identify long-running queries, frequently executed queries, etc.

Bending hibernate queries to your will can be really tricky, so you'll likely end up wanting to fix most of your query performance issues by caching frequently fetched data or playing with indexes and partitioning in your database.

Comment: Logging will take some CPU cycles, yes (another reason to be able to control logging as mentioned above!), but the vast majority of time is spent on database updates and queries in this case. AWR reports are usually helpful, but it is often easier to get plain logs from our customers, because they do not need involvement of busy DBAs, who we would rarely have much of a relationship with. The logs would also give the times of certain things, rather than a more statistical view, which can also be useful.